# How to use NDSolve and NSolve together

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have a differential equation that I can't solve analytically, so I use `NDSolve` to get a solution.

Suppose that I can't solve the next equation

```
sol = NDSolve[{D[p[x]/(1 + x)^3, x] == 0, p[0] == 1}, p, {x, 0, 1000}]
```

And know that I have the numerical solution, I want to find a solution of the equation $p[x]=100$ using `NSolve`:

```
NSolve[(p[x] /. sol) == 100, x, Reals]
```

However,  it doesn't work.

If I have the analytical solution of the differential equation this is easy, I just have to do the next,

```
Solve[(1 + x)^3 == 100, x, Reals]
```

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to go about this is to use the event detection capabilities of `NDSolve[]`, through `WhenEvent[]`:

```
{sol, {{xv}}} = 
Reap[NDSolveValue[{D[p[x]/(1 + x)^3, x] == 0, p[0] == 1, 
                   WhenEvent[p[x] == 100, Sow[x], "LocationMethod" -> "Brent"]}, 
                  p, {x, 0, 1000}]];

Plot[sol[x], {x, 0, 10}, GridLines -> {None, {100}},
     Epilog -> {Directive[ColorData[97, 2], AbsolutePointSize[6]], Point[{xv, sol[xv]}]}]
```

[image: solution]

Comment: I was looking for the numerical value, since I need this value for multiple calculations, it will be slow if I extract every single time the value from the graph.

Comment: "I was looking for the numerical value" - if you evaluated the code above, did you try evaluating just `xv` in a separate cell?

Comment: Oh, the graph don't appear in mathematica V.12, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just to be sure, please evaluate this on a freshly launched *Mathematica* instance. If that doesn't work, please take a screenshot and put it in a comment.

Comment: Thank you,  now I see the value. However I don't get the plot, is not necessary, but i would like to know how do you do that.

Comment: @Cruz - try the plot now

Comment: It works. Thank you once again.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to change variable names. Thanks @Bob!

Comment: @J.M. - been there, done that!

Answer (score 3):

Just drop the domain restriction. The domain restriction requires that all variables and functions to include intermediate values be real. Presumably, at some point Mathematica can't determine that and gives up.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)" *)

sol = NDSolve[{D[p[x]/(1 + x)^3, x] == 0, p[0] == 1}, p, {x, 0, 1000}][[1]];

NSolve[(p[x] /. sol) == 100, x][[1]] // Quiet

(* {x -> 3.64159} *)

Solve[(p[x] /. sol) == 100, x][[1]] // Quiet

(* {x -> 3.64159} *)
```